# Either postMessage or addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, html, postmessage

The following JavaScript code uses the HTML5 postMessage / addEventListener functions to send a message to itself:

```
window.addEventListener('testMsg', function(event) {
   alert('got a message');   /* Never happens. Why? */
}, false );

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
   alert('sending message');    
   window.postMessage('testMsg', '*');
}, false);
```

A corresponding fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGvLg/3/

The message is never received. What is the reason?

Comment: Where is the `testMsg` event defined ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have modified the fiddle. You were listening to the wrong event.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrbe/ZGvLg/4/)

Should be

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    alert('got a message');   /* Never happens. Why? */
}, false );

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    alert('sending message');    
    window.postMessage('message', '*');
}, false);
```

Comment: A few hours of work vs. 3 minutes on stack overflow, and the benefit of a fresh pair of eyes :) Thanks!

Comment: @MESSIAH — It is an event. It's the whole point of postMessage.

Answer (score 3):

You are listening for a `testMsg` event, but `postMessage` will trigger a `message` event.

Comment: Correct answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you need to listen for the `"message"` event, not `"testMsg"`. Here's a clearer code sample of working code

```js
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    alert('got a message'); // event.data == "hello world"
}, false );

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    alert('sending message');
    window.postMessage('hello world!', '*');
}, false);
```